# java - progression inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I have two classes, Progression and FibonacciProgression, however FibonacciProgression print out some unexpected results for when the print method is called on 4 and 6 as below. Can anyone explain WHY this is?

```
public class Progression {

    protected long first;
    protected long cur;

    Progression() {
        cur = first = 0;
    }

    protected long firstValue() {
        cur = first;
        return cur;
    }

    protected long nextValue() {
        return ++cur;
    }

    public void printProgression(int n) {
        System.out.print(firstValue());
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + nextValue());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Progression prog = new Progression();
        System.out.println("Default Progression: ");
        prog.printProgression(10);
    }

}
```

And..

```
public class FibonacciProgression extends Progression {

    protected long prev;

    FibonacciProgression(long value1, long value2) {
        first = value1;
        prev = value2 - value1;
    }

    FibonacciProgression() {
        this(0,1);
    }

    protected long nextValue() {
        long temp = prev;
        prev = cur;
        cur += temp;
        return cur;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Progression fibProg = new FibonacciProgression(2,5);
        System.out.println("Default Progression: ");
        fibProg.printProgression(4);
        fibProg.printProgression(6);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well they give different results: 2 5 7 12 & 2 9 11 20 31 51. So I'm wondering why the second one doesn't start off like the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are calling `printProgression` second time with parameter 6, the value of `prev` is not reset to it's initial value. `prev` still contains the value 7 from the last call. You need to save `value2` in `FibonacciProgression` and reset `prev` when `firstValue` of `FibonacciProgression` is called. Like this:

```
protected long firstValue() {
    prev = val2 - first;  // val2 is value2 passed in constructor
    return super.firstValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your printProgression "destroys" the value prev.
To easily see that it does, switch the main to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Progression fibProg = new FibonacciProgression(2, 5);
    System.out.println("Default Progression: ");
    fibProg.printProgression(4);
    fibProg = new FibonacciProgression(2, 5);
    fibProg.printProgression(6);
}
```

Comment: It does not destroy `cur`, `cur` is reset to its initial value in the call to `firstValue()`. Only `prev` is destroyed.

Comment: "cur" was destroyed until it gets reset, which is fine. I guess that is mostly a choice of words. But you are of course right. The general problem with @mark 's approach is that he is trying to do fib-like calculation but only saves/uses one value (in this case first) - when the series is dependant and decided by two values.